# $ \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+} , | x -y | < \epsilon \iff x = y $

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that for all  $ \epsilon > 0, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R} $ for every $ x, y \in \mathbb{R} $ if $ | x - y | < \epsilon \iff x = y$

(this question has similar ones in, but this one has the full proof, not only the hint).

Comment: That one don't have the full proof, just the hint.

Answer (score 0):

$( \Rightarrow ) $ I will prove by contraposition. Our affirmative states that:

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \; ( | x - y | < \epsilon ) \implies x = y
$$

The contrapositive is

$$
\lnot ( x = y ) \implies \lnot \forall \epsilon > 0 \; ( | x - y | < \epsilon ) \\
x \neq y  \implies  \exists \epsilon > 0 \; \lnot ( | x - y | < \epsilon ) \\
x \neq y \implies \exists \epsilon > 0 \; ( | x - y | \ge \epsilon )
$$

Therefore, if we prove the contrapositive, we have proved the affirmative. We need to find an $ \epsilon \le | x - y |$.

Let $ \epsilon = \frac{|x-y|}{2} $, since $ x \neq y $, without loss of generality,  let $ x > y $, that implies $ x - y > 0 $, since we have    $ | x - y | = x - y > 0 \implies | x - y | > 0 $.

Therefore $ | x - y | \ge \epsilon = \frac{|x-y|}{2} \implies 2 |x-y| \ge |x-y| $. That is true for all positive values, since we have proved our contraposition our initial hypothesis is valid.

$ ( \Leftarrow ) $ Direct proof. Let $ x = y \implies x - y = 0 \implies | x - y | = | 0 | < \epsilon \;\;\; \square$

Comment: Comments are welcome!